# idea can't find vm options file

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]
[image]
i can't find the vm options file

I looked up some articles on the Internet, but I didn't understand them，like this

https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_50216171/article/details/126986729
I understand that the vm options file may have been deleted, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to retrieve it

Comment: I did not take the initiative to modify or delete this file before, the idea version is 2023.1

Comment: Try installing Toolbox App that will manage this `.vmoptions` file. [1](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)

Comment: I have downloaded this app and reconfigured the memory size, but the button of idea help option is still gray, as shown in Figure 1

Comment: Try to close the IDE and manually create idea.vmoptions file in the IDE configuration directory https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory

Comment: If the problem remains, contact IntelliJ support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share the IDE logs `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data`

Comment: I specified a non-existent vmoptions file in the IDEA_VM_OPTIONS environment variable. This specified file overwrites the others via the idea documentation,

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties     search IDEA_VM_OPTIONS

Answer (score 0):

I specified a non-existent vmoptions file in the IDEA_VM_OPTIONS environment variable. This specified file overwrites the others via the idea documentation. [image]

So I created a new vmoptions file and deleted the variable